# Is there a way to check how I ended a mission in Mass Effect 2?

Tags: mass-effect-2

I beat Mass Effect 2 a while ago and I can't remember how Tali's loyalty mission ended. The journal entry says something like "Tali is grateful that her father was not exposed, but she is happy to leave the machinations of the Flotilla to return back to the Normandy." I can't tell if she was cleared of charges or convicted. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

The journal entry is pretty much all there is, and as long as you didn't expose her father, the text is the same whether you did it by talking your way out of it, or by getting her exiled. As far as I can tell, there are also no emails or repeatable dialogue options that reveal whether she was exiled or not.

The only way I can think of is to check your [Omni Tool Upgrades](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Upgrade_Guide#Omni-tool_Upgrades). If Tali was found innocent, you will have received an additional +10% Tech Damage upgrade, so if you have all 5 (6 if you have the Kasumi DLC), you'll know she wasn't exiled. If you don't, you can't really tell, since you may just have missed one.